# Node-XMPP stringprep error

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-xmpp

I'm using node-xmpp using browserify for web application. When I try to make a for browser file using browserify, the resulting file outputs this in js console -

> Cannot load StringPrep-0.1.0 bindings. You may need to `npm install
>   node-stringprep` client.js:5108 Cannot load StringPrep-0.2.3 bindings
>   (using fallback). You may need to `npm install node-stringprep`
>   client.js:34 Cannot load StringPrep-0.2.3 bindings (using fallback).
>   You may need to `npm install node-stringprep`

After which the code fails saying

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

The file client.js work fine when i use in terminal

> node client.js

There is nothing much in client.js

```
var xmpp = require('simple-xmpp');

xmpp.connect({
    jid                 : 'loginid',
    password            : 'password',
    host                : 'localhost',
    port                : 5222
});

xmpp.on('online', function() {
    console.log('Yes, I\'m connected!');
});

xmpp.on('chat', function(from, message) {
    xmpp.send(from, 'echo: ' + message);
});

xmpp.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});

xmpp.on('subscribe', function(from) {
if (from === 'a.friend@gmail.com') {
    xmpp.acceptSubscription(from);
    }
});
```

which I simply took from their documentation. Any pointers ??

Answer (score 2):

If its Fedora try

```
yum install libicu-devel
```

> libicu "provides Unicode and Globalization support for software
>   applications" and I guess the up-to-date version of this is needed by
>   node-xmpp.

On a Debian 6 system

```
apt-get install libicu-dev
```

might work.

https://github.com/node-xmpp/node-stringprep